# How to turn arrow into command

Tags: environments, preamble

I have found a symbol that I think is appropriate for a mathematical construct and this is the code for it

```
\ \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\circlearrowright$}\
```

I would like to just type \act instead of all that (will be used only in mathmode).
I tried writing this in the preamble

```
\newcommand{\act}{\ \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\circlearrowright$}\ }
```

but it didn't work, the compiler accuses me of Runaway argument. How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry but we can't read minds. If I add a document class, the document environment, and load the packages `graphicx` and `amssymb` everything works fine, so either you forgot one of these or there is something else you are withholding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the explicit spaces; quite likely you want a relation symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\act}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\act@\relax}}
\newcommand{\act@}[2]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\m@th#1\circlearrowright$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\act B$

$X_{A\act B}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you.